# Conditional deleting pairs inside a list of pairs

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of pairs for example like following:

```
list={{1,0.001},{10^(-7),0.001},{0.01,0.00005},{10^(-11),10^(-4)}}
```

Now I would like to delete all pairs (the complete pair), where the first element of the pair is smaller than 10^(-6).
I tried some complicated combination of a For-Next loop and an If condition but without success.
Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Luke

edit: extension: How would you do it, if I would have a list of lists of pairs? (Again delete the complete pair if the first element is smaller than some number)

Comment: `DeleteCases[list, {a_, _} /; a <= 10^(-6)]`

Comment: `Select[list, First@# > 10^(-6) &]`

Comment: `GroupBy[list, First@# > 10^(-6) &][True]`

Comment: Wow mathematica is amazing :) Thank you alot! How would you extend this if I would have a list of lists of pairs? (again delete the pairs if the first element is smaller than 10^(-5))

Comment: `list /. {a_ /; a <= 10^(-6), _} :> (## &[])`

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you, I would really appreciate if you (or someone else) could explain why that works step by step :)

Comment: Alternatively, use the `levelspec` on `DeleteCases`: `DeleteCases[list, {a_, _} /; a <= 10^(-6), {2}]`. You should use this one, not the last one (that was just for fun): look up the documentation for `DeleteCases` and look up pattern-matching.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(15381)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15381/removing-an-ordered-pair-from-a-list-of-ordered-pairs-if-the-second-element-in-t), [(27879)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27879/removing-pairs-that-meet-a-given-criterion-from-a-list?lq=1).

Comment: Related: [(11219)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11219/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy new way (since Mathematica 10.2) to remove some part from a list or expression is to replace that part with `Nothing`

For example you can do

```
list = {{1, 0.001}, {10^(-7), 0.001}, {0.01, 0.00005}, {10^(-11), 
    10^(-4)}};
list /. {a_ /; a <= 10^-6, _} -> Nothing
```

to get:

> {{1, 0.001}, {0.01, 0.00005}}

About the syntax:

- `/.` is `ReplaceAll`
- ... `->` ... is `Rule`
- `{a_ /; a <= 10^-6, _}` is a pattern with a `Condition`; you can read it "any pair with some first element/expression (say `a`) such that `a<=10^-6` and any second element (_ is `Blank`, any expression)"

The good (or, sometimes, maybe the bad) about this method is that easily translates to the "list of list (of list of list...) of pair". You don't need to change anything:

```
{list, list, list} /. {a_ /; a <= 10^(-6), _} -> Nothing
```

> {{{1, 0.001}, {0.01, 0.00005}}, {{1, 0.001}, {0.01, 
>      0.00005}}, {{1, 0.001}, {0.01, 0.00005}}}

This method it's just a variant of the "fun" approach of @march, but with an easy-to-understand (?) syntax, available since v10.2. Under a previous you still need to use an equivalent approach:

```
... /. {a_ /; a <= 10^(-6), _} -> Sequence[]
... /. {a_ /; a <= 10^(-6), _} -> (##&[]) (as of @march comment)
```

Using `Nothing`, `Sequence[]`, or `(##&[])` and `:>` or `->` is not always the same, but, for this sample, it is.

---

I also add another way:

```
Pick[list, UnitStep[list[[All, 1]] - 10^-6], 1]
```

> {{1, 0.001}, {0.01, 0.00005}}

not useful in the list of list of pair scenario and not exactly equivalent to the previous, but can have some other advantage:

```
list2 = Flatten[Table[list, {10000}], 1];
Pick[list2, UnitStep[list2[[All, 1]] - 10^-6], 1] // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
list2 /. {a_ /; a <= 10^-6, _} -> Nothing // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0338
>
> 0.0580

Comment: The way to do it pre-10.2 is `list /. {a_ /; a <= 10^(-6), _} :> (## &[])`, as in my comment above. I appreciate you writing it out in detail. +1.